# sql file containing the hierarchy of product categories

Tags: amazon-product-api

I want to store Amazon's hierarchy of product categories in a sql file. Is this possible to do using the Amazon Product Advertising API? If not, does anyone know if a source of a sql or csv file that contains a large hierarchy of product and service categories?

Answer (score 1):

While Amazon doesn't seem to give a full list of their BrowseNodes, it shouldn't be too difficult to generate one.

They give you [all of the parent nodes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html) as a starting point and then allow you to [use the BrowseNodeLookup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeLookup.html) to find info on a particular node including its parents/ancestors and children. With that function from their product advertising API, it shouldn't be difficult to recursively run through their browsenodes and create a full list - though it may need to be updated periodically.

Depending on your specific use-case, you might still be just as well off having your app use the BrowseNodeLookup each time it needs it to pull in the parent and child node info for navigation purposes (which I suspect is more what they prefer you to use it for).

It is worth noting by the way, that Amazon supposedly has around 120,000 different browsenodes in use and they change fairly often.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon has the notion of BrowseNodes to give their products some hierarchical structure. They do give you the [parent nodes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html) but to the best of my knowledge no complete list exists, probably because they retire and create nodes quite frequently.